# Can somebody explain what makes this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've hot React component which returns input tag. Can you please explain what is going on at the eighth line `ref={element => element && (element.onChange = onChange)}`? I

```
import React from 'react';

export default function MyInput({
    onChange,
    ...rest
}) {
    return (
        <input
            {...rest}
            ref={element => element && (element.onChange = onChange)}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React's `ref` is used to access the DOM directly, and in general is recommended to use as less as possible. The point of functional refs, and keep in mind that they're deprecated, is to assign the element into a class component's variable. e.g.:

```
Class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.inputRef = null;
  }

  ...stuff

  render() {
    ...stuff
    <input ref={element => this.inputRef = element} />
  }
}
```

Then, you could do something like:

```
this.inputRef.current.style.color = 'blue';
```

In your case, there is no need for this. If you want to assign the onChange you get from props, just do this:

```
<input {...stuff} onChange={onChange} />
```

Read more about React refs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

As for `element && element.onChange`, it's designed to make sure that `element` exists before accessing it's `onChange` property. Another way to do it, using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (only avaliable in react-scripts v3.3 and above), is this:

```
element?.onChange
```

Comment: `element &&` is a common pattern designed to make sure the element exist before accessing its property. If you tried to access `element.onChange` when `element` is `undefined`, the program will crash, with error `cannot access property 'onChange' of undefined`. I added an explenation to my answer.

Comment: But why we need to check its existence? We return this element, how can it doesn't exist? Did I correctly understand, that we just give <input> in return values event listener onChange?

Comment: @IWProgrammer At this particular case, indeed, its redundant. Feel free to remove it, and in general set the onChange as I suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Refs** are used to access DOM elements

The value of ref differs depending on the type of node:

1. When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref created
   in the constructor with React.createRef() receives the underlying
   DOM element as its current property.
2. When the ref attribute is used on a custom class component, the ref
   object receives the mounted instance of the component as its
   current.

They are used in cases where we want to change the value of a child component, without making use of props and all. But in your case, i think you have no need to use ref because you simply wants to assign onChange that you received from props.